# Url detection from firebase dynamic link returns nil iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

Firebase dynamic link url in iOS, is returning nil. It's worked well before, but doesn't work now.
userActivity.webpageURL having correct url, but dynamicLink.url is nil

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
continueUserActivity:(nonnull NSUserActivity *)userActivity
 restorationHandler:
#if defined(__IPHONE_12_0) && (__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_12_0)
(nonnull void (^)(NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> *_Nullable))restorationHandler {
#else
    (nonnull void (^)(NSArray *_Nullable))restorationHandler {
#endif  // __IPHONE_12_0

        NSURL *incomingUrl = userActivity.webpageURL;
        NSLog(@"Incoming url is: %@", incomingUrl);
        BOOL handled = [[FIRDynamicLinks dynamicLinks] handleUniversalLink:userActivity.webpageURL
                                                                completion:^(FIRDynamicLink * _Nullable dynamicLink,
                                                                             NSError * _Nullable error) {
            if (error != nil) {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@",error.localizedDescription);
                return;
            }
            if (dynamicLink != nil) {
                [self handleIncomingDynamicLink:dynamicLink];
            }
        }];
        return handled;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in devices running iOS13, before updating Firebase pods.

```
pod update Firebase
```

Now it works as intended, hope that helps.